# is this good topology for a quad-only mesh? what is this called?

Tags: vertices, topology

I'm very new to 3d modeling, and I've recently come across a very simple (and seemingly common) situation that I'm trying to find out a remedy for. I've heard very basic things about how having tris in a mesh that is designed to only have quads (as is default in Blender) is very bad, could show signs of topology, and potentially have further complications. As a result, I've focused a lot of my effort on trying to eliminate these from my models. However, I'm in a bit of a pickle.

[image]

What I'm trying to do here is to "dent" a cube, simply replacing one vertex of it with a triangular face. I've achieved this by removing the vertex, replacing it with two extrusions from another vertex, and connecting vertices up. In theory, this doesn't create any tris (every single face is supported by 4 vertices). But something still looks wrong about this, and I have no idea what it is. Part of it seems to be that there doesn't seem to be any calculatable edge loop at the end face of this cube, as the edge loop has an edge in its midst, but this isn't bad, right?

Is this valid or "good" topology? If so, what's this referred to or how could I figure out more about this? If not, how would I fix this simple example? Help is greatly appreciated, thanks bunches :D

Comment: Hello. This depends on how the target application will divide the quads when rendering. Since these 3 points are colinear https://i.stack.imgur.com/lz4Xy.png if they are used to create a triangle, it will be a zero-area triangle which may or may not cause problems down the line.

Comment: hi, thanks! that does make sense, although I'm simply aiming to create a "perfect" model; this isn't aimed to be used in a game or any rendering engine. but that does make sense

Comment: Depends on what you want to do with it. Also there is a pole (Vertex with more than 4 edges connected to it)Tris, N-gons and poles can mess up your model pretty quickly, but they can be used to our advantage as well. Everything depends on the situation though.

Comment: I agree with Akshay2005, it depends on what is your goal, the "perfect" model will be the one that fits your need, you don't necessarily need to avoid tris and ngons

Comment: In addition to what Gorgious said about potential triangulation problems, these "degenerate quads" (3 or more colinear vertices) can break a lot of operations, and provide none of the benefits of quad modelling.  But topo is mesh-dependent.  With what you are showing-- flat shaded, no subdivision-- you'd be better off with triangles and ngons.  Quad modelling is important, *in conjunction with good edge flow*, for smooth shaded normals; and *in conjunction with pole control* for C-C subdivision.  Quad modelling is *part of a recipe* for good topo.  It is not everything.